# Não entra no if

Tags: php

tenho uma função mas a mesma não esta entrando no if...

```
/**
 * funcao que trocas os valores por "?"
 * @param type $condicao : ex "codigo = 1, AND, nome = 2, OR, secao = 1" ou "codigo = 1, AND, nome = rafael" ou "codigo = 1";
 * @return type ex: "codigo = ? AND nome = ? OR secao = ?" 
 */
function prepareCondReadInterrogacao($condicao) {
    $val = explode(",", $condicao);
    $temp = "";
    foreach ($val as $value) {
        if (!strcmp($value, "AND") || !strcmp($value, "OR")) {
            echo 'entrei';
            $val2 = explode("=", $value);
            $val2[1] = " ?";
            $value = implode("=", $val2);
        }
        $temp .= $value . " ";
    }

    return $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se testou com espaços na *string*, não é para entrar mesmo. `' AND'` e `'AND'` são coisas distintas.

Uma solução seria esta:

```
if (!strcmp(trim($value), 'AND') || !strcmp(trim($value), 'OR')) {
```

Aí vem outro problema de lógica:

Se o valor for `AND`, ele não vai ser `OR`, se for `OR` não vai ser `AND`. Sempre vai ser verdadeira a expressão acima. Provavelmente você procura isto:

```
if (!strcmp(trim($value), 'AND') && !strcmp(trim($value), 'OR')) {
```

Que pode ser simplificado para isto:

```
if (!trim($value)=='AND') && !trim($value)=='OR') {
```

Ou melhor, para isto:

```
if (!in_array($value, array('AND','OR'))) {
```

Caso queira verificar tanto `and` quanto `AND`, pode usar isto:

```
if (!in_array(strtoupper($value), array('AND','OR'))) {
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9KCAyw)**.

Pontos de interesse:

- `trim` serve para remover espaços (ou outros caracteres) do começo e fim de uma *string*;
- `strtoupper` retorna uma versão em maiúscula da *string* (normalmente se usa `mb_strtoupper` se for para caracteres acentuados e/ou especiais);
- `in_array` verifica se um valor buscado está em alguma das posições de um *array*;
- quando você inverte duas condições lógicas, precisa normalmente revisar o operador que une as duas; exemplo:  o inverso de `$a=1 OR $b=1` é `!$a=1 AND !$b=1` ou `!($a=1 OR $b=1)`.

Comment: eu preciso que ele me retorne uma string assim : "codigo = ? AND nome = ? OR secao = ?", sendo a entrada essa: "codigo = 1, AND, nome = 2, OR, secao = 1"

Comment: @RafaelSilva ah, entao é só deixar fora do loop mesmo. Mas o resto acho que ta certo.

Comment: Corrigido: http://ideone.com/9KCAyw

Comment: Depois, se você testar o segundo valor se tem aspas ou não, já pode determinar se é string ou numero, se for fazer bind.

Comment: Perfeito cara, muito obrigado! To indo nos trancos e barrancos com php rsrs, meu forte é java Android. Estou desenvolvendo meu web-server na unha! Muito gostoso, gosto de desafios...

Comment: Beleza, qualquer dúvida sobre este problema, deixe um comentário, ou sobre outros, abra uma nova pergunta, que o que estiver no alcance a gente ajuda. O mais importante é você entender o que foi feito, para reaproveitar o conhecimento em situações futuras.